# Put quotes between comma-separated values

Tags: shell

How can I put quotes in between values?

- Input: `A00W,B00W,C00W`
- Output: `'A00W','B00W','C00W'`

Answer (score 0):

There's the naive `awk` solution:

```
echo foo,bar,baz | awk "{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf( \"'%s'%c\", \$i, i == NF ? \"\\n\" : \",\")}"  FS=,
```

and the naive `perl` solution:

```
echo foo,bar,baz | perl -054 -lpe "s/(.*)/'\1'/"
```

and:

```
echo foo,bar,baz | sed -E "s/([^,]*)(,|\$)/'\1'\2/g"
```

It's not too bad to do:

```
printf "'%s'," $(echo foo,bar,baz | tr , \\n) | sed 's/,$//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer as a bash script.

```
#! /bin/bash

while IFS=, read -ra arr; do
    
        for item in ${arr[@]}
        do
            printf "'$item',"  >> temp
        done

sed '$ s/.$//' temp  >  outputFile


done < inputFile
```